# Add percentage change and range of historical values into results of Pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: `Race` and `Odds`. One race has many odds including historical odds for each horse. In my pivot table I show the `average` of the historical prices for each horse for each website.

What I want is to add a two more columns: a column that calculates the `percentage change` (% change = (first odd-last odd) ÷ first odd × 100) and a column that includes all the `historical odds` in a field. I am not sure how to include the data for these two fields in aggregation. Any ideas?

Desired results

```
|     Name | OddsRaceID |    ABC |    DEF |    GHI |    IJK |    OPQ |  %  | All HistorOdds|
|----------|------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|-----|---------------|
|   Jonner |          1 |  2.032 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |13.3%| 1.50,1.60,1.70|
|   Seller |          1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |-63.6% | 11,12,4       |
| Show off |          1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | 5.4166 | (null) | ..%  | 9,3,4         |
|  Stander |          1 | (null) | 1.5933 | (null) | (null) | (null) | ..% | 1.40          |
|    Super |          1 | (null) | (null) |    5.2 | (null) | (null) | ..% | 5,5.5,6.5     |
|    Taryn |          1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |   11.5 | ..% | 15,12         |
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1bda/8)

Comment: It's Friday I don't think anyone wants to deal with CSV values stored in columns. Make HistoricalOdds another table with a 1:N relationship and stop concatenating data pieces in your columns.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT - Corrected for Typo**

Here is one option using a subquery and a simple join

**Example**

```
SELECT piv1.* 
      ,[%Change]   = format((B.Odd2-B.Odd1) / B.Odd1,'0.0%')
      ,AllHistOdds = B.Hist
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT Name, AVG(Odds) AS Odds, WebsiteName,OddsRaceID FROM ArbiOdds GROUP BY WebsiteName, Name, OddsRaceID) AS SourceTable
            PIVOT 
            (
                 AVG(Odds) 
                 FOR WebsiteName IN
                 ([ABC],[DEF],[GHI],[IJK],[OPQ])
            ) as bob
     ) piv1 
 Join (
        Select Name
              ,OddsID
              ,Odd1 = max(case when RN1=1 then Odds end) 
              ,Odd2 = max(case when RN2=1 then Odds end)
              ,Hist = Stuff((Select ',' +cast(Odds as varchar(25)) From ArbiOdds Where Name=O.Name and OddsID=O.OddsID Order By DateUTC For XML Path   ('')),1,1,'')
         From (
                Select Name
                      ,Odds
                      ,OddsID
                      ,RN1 = Row_Number() over (Partition By Name,OddsID Order By DateUTC) 
                      ,RN2 = Row_Number() over (Partition By Name,OddsID Order By DateUTC Desc) 
                 from ArbiOdds
              ) O
         Group By Name,OddsID
      ) B on B.Name=piv1.name and B.OddsID=piv1.OddsRaceID
ORDER BY piv1.name
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: I just noticed on here 'B on B.Name=piv1.name and B.OddsID=piv1.OddsRaceID' you join OddsID with OddsRaceID which shouldn't match. Each Odd has an OddsID and the ArbiRace.OddsRaceID is the foreign key of ArbiRace(RaceID)

Comment: @alwaysVBNET Your sample keys were a little generic, so I made an assumption.  Looking into it

Comment: @alwaysVBNET A little stuck.  Are you expecting expecting multiple records by Name, RaceID, and OddsID

Comment: I believe the generic query should do for all the races. Then I could do add 'where RaceID=n'

Comment: there should be one record for each horse

Comment: @alwaysVBNET Yes there is.  However, for the Pivot, you are averaging the odds for the entire set (regardless of OddID and RaceID). but you desired results includes only RaceID 1

Comment: @alwaysVBNET given your sample data. what would be the AllHist for Jonner

Comment: it should be 1.50, 1.60, 1.70 for race 1. The problem is that there might be a duplicate name between races.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*,
       B.Percentage as '%Change',
       C.All_HistorOdds
FROM

(
SELECT piv1.*
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT Name, AVG(Odds) AS Odds, WebsiteName,OddsRaceID FROM ArbiOdds GROUP BY WebsiteName, Name, OddsRaceID) AS SourceTable
            PIVOT 
            (
                 AVG(Odds) 
                 FOR WebsiteName IN
                 ([ABC],[DEF],[GHI],[IJK],[OPQ])
            ) as bob
     ) piv1 
) as A

INNER JOIN 
(

SELECT ROUND(((first_odd-last_odd)*1.0/first_odd) * 100,1) as Percentage,FIRST.Name
FROM
(
SELECT odds as first_odd,Name
FROM 
    (
        SELECT odds,Name, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY oddsID,NAME ORDER BY DateUTC ASC) as rownumber
    FROM ArbiOdds
    WHERE OddsID = 1
    ) as GET_FIRSTODD
WHERE GET_FIRSTODD.rownumber = 1
) as FIRST

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT odds as last_odd,Name 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT odds,Name, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY oddsID,NAME ORDER BY DateUTC DESC) as rownumber
    FROM ArbiOdds
       WHERE OddsID = 1
    ) as GET_FIRSTODD
WHERE GET_FIRSTODD.rownumber = 1
) as LAST
ON LAST.Name = FIRST.Name


) as B

ON B.Name = A.Name


INNER JOIN 

(
SELECT Name,STUFF((
SELECT ',' + cAST(Odds as varchar(50))
              FROM ArbiOdds as A
              WHERE OddsID = 1 AND A.Name = B.Name
              FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') as 'All_HistorOdds'
FROM ArbiOdds as B
GROUP BY Name
) as C

ON C.Name = A.Name
```

Comment: On the last column All_HistorOdds the numbers appear as .50001.60001.7000 instead of 1.50000, 1.60000, 1.700000 How should this be managed?

Comment: I noticed that issue, too but did not find any issue with the `STUFF` function, could you try to run in your MS? I am checking again now

Comment: I had the stuff function like this in previous attempts: STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(WebsiteName)
                      FROM ArbiOdds
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')